# A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

We have an in-house developed VB.Net Windows Forms application that is losing users' individual connections to the SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

The bolded message below is what appears.

A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

I have looked at many numerous articles both from Microsoft and others, but have been unable to pinpoint the issue.

Sometimes it occurs when the user has been away from the open application for a long-time; others maybe less than 20 minutes.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you open a connection and then leave it open for the whole time the App's running? If so, try explicitly closing it after each set of database transactions and opening it again when needed. This sounds like the remote db server is just closing the (unused) open connection for you.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the network connection is suddenly lost. It happens to me when I open my SQL Server and walk away for a long time and come back it happens.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider, first check the Firewall of the server and create inbound and outbound rules for SQL server. Then if there are any antivirus in the system take a look into its behavior.